# can't change global variable inside function using parameter in python

Tags: python, variables, parameters, pickle

```
import pickle
    
    name = 'something'
    
    def save(variable, value):
        obj = str(value)
        file = f'{variable}.pkl'
        fileObj = open(file, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(obj, fileObj)
        global variable
        variable = value
        fileObj.close()
    
    def read(variable):
        file = f'{variable}.pkl'
        with open(file, 'rb') as oFile:
            content = pickle.load(oFile)
            print(content)
            oFile.close()
    
    save(name, 'else')
    print('!! > ',name)
    read(name)
```

**Error:**
File "h:/PythonProjects/Python.py", line 10
global variable
SyntaxError: name 'variable' is used prior to global declaration

any suggestions about how to change global variable with a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using the global statement, you need to define a global variable...

```
variable = None

def bla():
    global variable
    variable = 22
```

Comment: I want to use a parameter to call any variable in my code